# Prove an inequality by using the integral test or another way

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives, inequality, convex-analysis

‎Let the function ‎‎$‎g:‎\mathbb{R^+}‎‎‎\rightarrow‎‎\mathbb{R^+}‎$ ‎have ‎the ‎properties ‎that‎‎ for each ‎$‎w>0‎$‎, ‎
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}‎\frac{g(x+w)}{g(x)} = 1‎
$$ and $\log g(x)‎$ ‎is ‎concave‎. ‎Now, since ‎$‎\log g‎$ ‎is ‎concave, ‎so ‎it ‎has ‎derivative‎
$$
\big(\log g(x)\big)^\prime=\frac{g^\prime_-(x)+g^\prime_+(x)}{2g(x)}
$$
except, possibly, on a countable set,  where ‎$‎g^\prime_{+}(x‏)‎$ ‎and ‎‎$‎g^\prime_{-}(x)‎$ ‎are ‎right ‎and ‎left ‎derivatives, ‎respectively. Also, since 
$$
‎‎‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}}‎\frac{g(x+w)}{g(x)} = 1‎
$$ for each ‎$‎w>0‎$  and $\log g(x)‎$ ‎is ‎concave, ‎then ‎‎$‎g‎$ ‎is ‎increasing. ‎Now, ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎my ‎questions ‎is:‎‎ ‎‏‎

How should I prove the following inequality?‎
$$
0\leq\gamma_g+\log g(1)\le \frac{g^\prime_-(1)+g^\prime_+(1)}{2g(1)},
‎$$
where 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{g^\prime_-(i)+g^\prime_+(i)}{2g(i)}\to \gamma_g\text{ as }n\to\infty.
$$

**Hint**. Note that we can using the proof of the integral test for the convergence of infinite series, for the proof inequality (but I can't prove it).

Comment: Did you prove the case when $g$ is differentiable on $(0, +\infty)$?

Comment: River Li. No. I was reading an article entitled log-convex solutions to the functional equation ....  of Roger Webster, which I face with in the above inequality, which is found in page 621 of article and I couldn't solve the inequality.

Comment: See. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X97953439

Comment: I think that you may misunderstand something. I think that in the paper, the problem is to prove that $\sum_{i=1}^n‎‎‎\frac{g^\prime_{-}(i) + g^\prime_{+}(i) ‎}{2g(i)} - \log g(n)$ converges and its limit is‎ $‎‎\gamma‎_g$ (also $\gamma_g$ satisfies the inequality), not to assume the existence of limit then to prove $\gamma_g$ satisfies the inequality. How do you think?

Comment: River Li. Thanks. How should I prove?

Comment: I wrote something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hypothesis imply that $\log g$ is absolutely continuous on compact sets, i.e., there is a function $h:\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\log g(x) = \log g(a) + \int_a^x h(t)\; dt,
$$
for all $a,x\in \mathbb{R}^+$. After redefining $h$ on a set of measure zero if necessary, we can assume that
$$
h(x) = \frac{g'_-(x)+g'_+(x)}{2g(x)}
$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$. Again, the hypothesis imply that $h$ is decreasing and non-negative. Now,
$$
h(i+1)\leq \int_i^{i+1} h(t)\; dt \leq h(i)
$$
and then
$$
\sum_{i=2}^n h(i) \leq \int_1^n h(t)\; dt \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} h(i),
$$
so we obtain
$$
\sum_{i=2}^n h(i) - \log g(n) + \log g(1) \leq 0 \qquad \text{ and } \qquad 0\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} h(i)- \log g(n) + \log g(1)
$$
that we can rewrite as
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n h(i) - \log g(n) + \log g(1) \leq \frac{g'_-(1)+g'_+(1)}{2g(1)} \qquad \text{ and } \qquad 0\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} h(i)- \log g(n) + \log g(1) - h(n).
$$
Now, $h$ is decreasing and non-negative, so the limit $L=\lim_{n\to\infty} h(n)$ exists and $L\geq 0$, so
$$
\gamma_g+\log g(1)\leq \frac{g'_-(1)+g'_+(1)}{2g(1)} \qquad \text{ and } \qquad 0\leq \gamma_g+\log g(1)-L,
$$
that is
$$
0\leq L\leq \gamma_g+\log g(1) \leq \frac{g'_-(1)+g'_+(1)}{2g(1)}
$$
as desired.

Comment: Albert. Thanks for solving the problem. Why $h$ is decreasing and non-negative?

Comment: $h$ is decreasing because $\log g$ is concave, and $h$ is non-negative because $g$ is increasing, and so is $\log g$.

Comment: Albert. How to get $‎h(i+1)\leq\int_{i}^{i+1} h(t)dt\leq h(i)‎$‎?

Comment: Since $h$ is decreasing and $i+1>i$, so $h(i+1)\leq h(i)$, but I do not solve ‎‎$‎h(i+1)\leq\int_{i}^{i+1} h(t)dt\leq h(i)‎$.

Comment: For $i\leq t\leq i+1$ you get that $h(i+1)\leq h(t)\leq h(i)$. Integrate with respect to $t$ this inequality from $i$ to $i+1$.

Comment: Albert. Thanks. Why ‎‎$‎h(n)\rightarrow ‎0‎$ ‎as ‎‎$‎n‎‎\rightarrow ‎\infty‎$‎‎?

Comment: That's a really good question! We don't really need the fact that $h(n)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ (and thinking about it, I don't believe this is always the case). All we need is that $h(n)\to L$ as $n\to\infty$ for some $L\geq 0$. I will make some edits in my answer!

Comment: Albert. Why if ‎$‎h‎$ ‎is ‎decreasing ‎and ‎non-negative, ‎then‎ the limit ‎$L = ‎\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}} h(n)‎$‎ exists and ‎$‎L\geq 0‎$‎?

Comment: It is a well known fact that any monotone bounded sequence of real numbers converges. Also it is a well known fact that if $(a_n)$ converges to $a$ and $a_n \geq M$ (resp.  $a_n \leq M$) for all $n$ then $a \geq M$ (resp. $a \leq M$).

Answer (score 1):

Too long for comment

First, let us clarify the problem. We rephrase the problem as follow (cf. the OP).
I put an image snipped from the article later.

Let $g: (0, \infty) \to (0, \infty)$ be a function such that
$\log g(x)$ is concave, and $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{g(x+w)}{g(x)} = 1$ for each fixed $w > 0$.
Then:
*Fact 1*: $g(x)$ is increasing;
*Fact 2*: $\frac{g'_{-}(x) + g'_{+}(x)}{2g(x)}$ is decreasing and non-negative on $(0, \infty)$, 
where $g'_{+}(x)$ and $g'_{-}(x)$ are the right and left derivatives;
*Fact 3*: $\log g(x)$ has derivative $\frac{g'_{-}(x) + g'_{+}(x)}{2g(x)}$ except, possibly, on a countable set.
Let
$$F(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{g'_{-}(i) + g'_{+}(i)}{2g(i)}  - \log g(n) .$$
Prove that the sequence $\{F(n)\}$ converges.
Also, by denoting $\lim_{n\to\infty} F(n) = \gamma_g$, prove that
$$0 \le \gamma_g + \log g(1) \le \frac{g'_{-}(1) + g'_{+}(1)}{2g(1)}.\tag{1}$$

*Image snipped from the article*

[image: Image snipped from the article]

Comment: River Li. Thanks for guide.

Comment: @koohyareslami You are welcome.

Comment: River Li.  ‎Why‎ $‎‎‎‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}‎F(n)‎$ ‎exists? ‎Since,‎ From Stolz-Cesaro theorem we conclude ‎‎$‎‎‎‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}‎\frac{F(n)}{n}‎$ ‎exist.

Comment: @koohyareslami   You are right. I made a mistake. I will delete this part in my answer.